# In java.time, why does WeekFields.SUNDAY_START produce a week number of 1 for 2020-12-29 instead of 53?

Tags: java, datetime

I'm sure I'm just missing something here, but it continues to elude me.

Why does SUNDAY_START produce a week number of 1 for 2020-12-29 instead of 53?

Is it because I'm misinterpreting what the Oracle docs say? Or am I missing something further?

**Details**

Going to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#SUNDAY_START shows that SUNDAY_START appears to follow the same rules as above. If I use the following code...

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(/* representation of Dec. 29, 2020 */, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
 
TemporalField wn = WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.weekOfWeekBasedYear();
    
int weekNumber = zdt.get(wn);
```

Then "weekNumber" is 1, when I would expect it to be 53.

If I use `WeekFields.ISO` instead, I get 53; however, the definition of ISO is that it uses Monday as the start of the week, which isn't true in the case I'm dealing with and I'm unsure of future ramifications of just using ISO instead of SUNDAY_START.

What am I missing?

**The Answer**

Based on the comments below (thank you to Basil and Andreas), I was indeed misreading the Oracle documentation, which states:

`Defined as starting on Sunday and with a minimum of 1 day in the month.`

The "minimum of 1 day in the month" was the part that threw me for a loop within the context of a new year.

With the clarifications below, it's clear that since Jan. 1, 2021 occurs on a Friday, and the SUNDAY_START week starts on a Sunday, that this week would, in fact, be week number 1 in this case.

**Motivation**

I had originally asked this question as part of an attempt to better understand SUNDAY_START. The motivation for this was to find a way to recreate MySQL's WEEK() "mode 6" (that is, a Sunday start to the week with week 1 being the first week with 4 or more days this year).

I had forgotten about the ability to create custom week fields with a specified start day and the minimum number of days in the month for it to contain.

Still, I am grateful to have cleared up my misunderstanding of the Javadocs for SUNDAY_START, and I hope this post might be useful to someone in the future.

Thank you for everyone's comments and answers and I apologize for any initial confusion.

Comment: I don't think so: I've actually been using Instant.now() as the "representation" since today is Dec. 29, 2020, and I get the results above.

Comment: `WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() == 1`. There are 2 days of 2021 in this (sunday-started) week: 1st and 2nd. At least from this POV week 1 is logical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://savvytime.com/week-number is **wrong**.

When you show `Country: United States`, `Year: 2020`, it shows:

```
Week 53   December 27, 2020   January 2, 2021   Current Week
```

When you show `Country: United States`, `Year: 2021`, it shows:

```
Week 1    December 27, 2020   January 2, 2021   Current Week
```

How can the same date range be both week 53 *and* week 1? It can't. The site is broken.

---

**UPDATE:** From comment:

> needing a Java datetime "equivalent" of MySQL's [`WEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function using mode 6

That's easy enough. Mode 6 is defined as:

- **First day of week:** Sunday
- **Week 1 is the first week...** with 4 or more days this year

So you get a `WeekFields` for that:

```java
WeekFields weekMode6 = WeekFields.of(/*firstDayOfWeek=*/DayOfWeek.SUNDAY,
                                     /*minimalDaysInFirstWeek=*/4);
```

For reference, the two predefined `WeekFields` instances are defined as:

```java
ISO         = new WeekFields(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 4);
SUNDAY_START = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 1);
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do with rules only pertaining to year in question, but you raise an interesting point.

Interestingly enough, https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/custom.html?country=1&wno=1&moon=on&hol=25 states, "Week numbers: Week starts Sunday - week 1 is the one with January 1." ...which would make Dec. 29, 2020 in week 1. But again it might boil down to some rules I'm unaware of.

Comment: is there actually a rule that a week can't be in 2 years at once in that numbering system? (The ISO system explicitly prevents that, but I don't know about the US system)

Comment: That's what I'm wondering myself. Really the most frustrating part for me is needing a Java datetime "equivalent" of MySQL's WEEK() function using mode 6. SUNDAY_START seems to be the closest, but evidently there's at least one significant difference.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor What difference is that? If you wanted a Java version of MySQL's `WEEK()` function using mode 6, then why didn't you ask for that?

Comment: Because I'm also trying to understand what is documented in the Java time library. I was hoping that by increasing my understanding of the specifics of the library, I'd be able to determine a solution. If I can correct my understanding as I go, then I'm better off than just asking for a copy/paste answer.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor Well, that backfired, since you based the entire question on the flawed output from some website, and asked why Java differed from the web site, which lead to answers that were entirely off point to your actual question.

Comment: Evidently, and I apologize for that. I had only looked at the initial output (which appeared correct) and hadn't gone to the next year to verify all output. Regardless, I believe your last edit above is likely what I'm looking for to correct the situation, despite wondering if I misinterpreted what Oracle said about SUNDAY_START. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

## Not so savvy SavvyTime.com

Your linked web site uses undisclosed rules for defining a week:

> Weeks are according United States calendar rules, Sunday first day and weeks are Sunday to Saturday

The phrase “United States calendar rules” has no meaning. There are many sets of calendar rules in the US: Various accounting organizations make rules, IRS has rules, industries have their own rules such as a two-season year in some retail, and private companies define their own rules, sometimes [quite innovative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Fixed_Calendar).

And the rest of that definition is unclear.

Furthermore, that site seems to be inexplicably self-contradictory, as seen in the [Answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499797/642706).

I would not consider that web site to be authoritative.

## ISO 8601

In contrast, the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) calendar is very clearly defined, including the [definition of a week and week-based-year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

- Weeks start on a Monday, end on Sunday.
- Week-based years have either 52 or 53 whole weeks.
- Week number 1 contains the first Thursday in the calendar year.

This definition means that a week-based year may contain a few days from the previous calendar year in week # 1, and may contain a few days from the following calendar-year in the last week of the week-based year.

Am not sure exactly what your goal is, as your Question is unclear. But if the ISO 8601 rules match those of your business, then use the implementation in *java.time*.

### *ThreeTen-Extra* and `YearWeek`

Even better, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This library is led by the same man who led the *java.time* JSR 310 project, Stephen Colebourne. This library brings additional functionality to *java.time*. In particular, see the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class for ISO 8601 weeks.

Comment: Totally agreed ISO is way more clear. I wish I could use it! As it is, I'm forced to use a system where Sunday is the start of the week, where week 1 is the first week with 4 or more days for the given year (i.e. MySQL's WEEK() using mode 6). I'm looking for a way to do the same thing in Java. SUNDAY_START (as opposed to ISO) seemed to be the way to go, but it's apparent that there are differing rules. Maybe I'm not reading "Defined as starting on Sunday and with a minimum of 1 day in the month." correctly. Regardless, I still need the Java equivalent, if one exists.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor Your should edit your question for clarity. Focus on what you *do* want, and try to eliminate distractions unless they provide a specific contrast.

Comment: To be fair, the question is rather clear: Why does SUNDAY_START produce a week number of 1 for 2020-12-29 instead of 53? Is it because I'm misinterpreting what the Oracle docs say? Or am I missing something further? I had hoped once that was answered that I'd be able to better understand what I was using and come up with a solution, and ask a separate question if necessary. I now regret having brought up the equivalency request as it was meant to serve as motivation.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor Because it's the right answer for SUNDAY_START, given that 2020-12-29 is a Tuesday, so it crosses into the new year, and SUNDAY_START is defined as *"first week has a minimum of 1 day"*, so that week is by that definition week 1.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor Bingo, now we have a specific question, in that first sentence of your comment. I edited the title to replace the vague one with that one.

Comment: Basil, you said "as your Question is unclear", which is entirely true, since OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499411/problem-understanding-java-times-weekfields-sunday-start/65499797?noredirect=1#comment115801721_65499797): *"needing a Java datetime "equivalent" of MySQL's `WEEK()` function using mode 6"*

Comment: @Andreas thank you! So I was misunderstanding what was meant by "...has a minimum of 1 day." That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you for your assistance in this. I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: @BtySgtMajor Good that you sorted out a solution. Please edit the body of your Question to suit, so this page can be a resource for others.

Comment: @BasilBourque will do. Wish I could mark both answers as the right one.